# Changing material color on a merged mesh with three js

Tags: three.js, opengl-es-2.0, webgl

Is that possible to interact with the buffer used when merging multiple mesh for changing color on the selected individual mesh ?

It's easy to do such thing with a collection of mesh but what about a merged mesh with multiple different material ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you mean with "changing colors". Note that after merging, the mesh is like any other non-merged mesh.

If you mean vertex colors, it would be possibly to iterate over the faces and determine the vertices which color to change based on the material index.

If you mean setting a color to the material itself, sure it's possible. Merged meshes can still have multiple materials the same way ordinary meshes do - in `MeshFaceMaterial`, though if you are merging yourself, you need to pass in a material index offset parameter for each geometry.

Comment: thanx for the precision, i think we're good, changing color to the materielIndex of the clicked mesh (merged 200 mesh to one), gonna check this out

Answer (score 3):

@hgates, your last comment was very helpful to me, I was looking for the same thing for days !

> Ok i set on each face a color, and set to true vertexColor on the
>   material, that solve the problem ! :)

I write here the whole concept that I used in order to add a proper answer for those who are in the same situation :

```
// Define a main Geometry used for the final mesh
var mainGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();

// Create a Geometry, a Material and a Mesh shared by all the shapes you want to merge together (here I did 1000 cubes)
var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: true});
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry );

var i = 0;

for ( i; i<1000; i++ ) {

    // I set the color to the material for each of my cubes individually, which is just random here
    cubeMaterial.color.setHex(Math.random() * 0xffffff);

    // For each face of the cube, I assign the color
    for ( var j = 0; j < cubeGeometry.faces.length; j ++ ) {
        cubeGeometry.faces[ j ].color = cubeMaterial.color;
}

    // Each cube is merged to the mainGeometry
    THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(mainGeometry, cubeMesh);
 }

 // Then I create my final mesh, composed of the mainGeometry and the cubeMaterial
 var finalMesh = new THREE.Mesh( mainGeometry, cubeMaterial );
 scene.add( finalMesh );
```

Hope it will help as it helped me ! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
this.meshMaterials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
    {color:0x00ff00 * Math.random(), side:THREE.DoubleSide}));

for ( var face in geometry.faces ) {
  geometry.faces[face].materialIndex = this.meshMaterials.length-1;
}

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry);

THREE.GeometryUtils.merge(this.globalMesh, mesh);
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.globalMesh, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(this.meshMaterials));
```

Works like a charm, for those who need example but ! This creates mutliple additional buffers (indices and vertex data) , and multiple drawElements call too :(, i inspect the draw call with webgl inpector, **before adding the MeshFaceMaterial : 75 call opengl api** running at 60fps easily, **after : 3490 call opengl api** fps drop about 20 % 45-50 fps, this means that drawElements is called for every mesh, we loose the context of merging meshes, did i miss something here ? i want to share different materials on the same buffer

Comment: no one got an answer ? I want to minimize the draw call, with this code, i'm able to build one mesh with multiple material, but too many draw call, please need answers or tips, anything, if u have any idea !!

Comment: Ok i set on each face a color, and set to true vertexColor on the material, that solve the problem ! :)